# Why does expo makes Internet doesn't work?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, native, expo

I'm currently learning React Native. For this, I'm using a wsl (Ubuntu) and expo for testing on my android device.
So my problem is very weird and I haven't found anything similar on the Internet.
So whenever I need to test my app on my device I type expo start and everything works fine. After about 15min I cannot use Internet anymore : when I want to visit a website it says "This website cannot be reached", the error code is ERR_CONNECTION_FAILED (Google Chrome but same thing with other web browsers).
I know this is weird. This only happens when I work with React Native. It might be something about nodejs I don't know I really don't understand the link between Internet and Expo.

I tried to reinstall nodejs npm and expo, this didn't change anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/99

Comment: Thank you ! So it seems there is no solution yet ..

Answer (score 0):

As per 
https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/99

1 - WIN+R -> services.msc
2 - Find LxssManager
3 - Right-click -> Restart

sadly this kills the expo environment! and issue repeats, until WSL fixes its issues, using CMD is the only viable choice with Expo on Windows as of now (March 2020)